# how to get unique value from an array of hashtable in powershell?

Tags: powershell

how to get unique value from an array of hashtable in powershell?

```
$h1 = @{a=1;b=2};
$h2 = @{a=3;b=4};
$h3 = @{a=1;b=2};

$h = $h1,$h2,$h3
```

I want to remove duplicate value ($h1 or $h3) from $h.

thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
$h | select @{ Expression = { "$($_.Keys):$($_.Values)" }; Label ="AsString" }, @{ Expression ={$_}; Label = "Hash" } -unique 
                      | select -expand Hash
```

Comment: @manojlds - I don't know if it can be simplified. You can wait for some other answers ;)

Comment: Seems not to be simplified, time is running ;)